# Calculate exact number of primes up to N

Tags: prime-numbers

How can I calculate exactly how many primes there are up to 65,025?

I have seen that $x/logx$ gives an estimation, but it is not hugely accurate.

Comment: By, for example, the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @Ragnar1204 I don't get why Euler's totient function is relevant here.

Comment: Sorry by the last commen it was posted by a work-partner... really I'm sorry.

Comment: If this is a problem in a computer science class, then look up "Sieve of Eratosthenes."

Comment: You can do better with the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime-counting_function_in_terms_of_the_logarithmic_integral) but that is still not exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Wolfram alpha and type

PrimePi(65025)

This is called prime counting function.